# Splitting a string variable into chunks 16 characters long

Tags: python, string, split, raspberry-pi, lcd

I'm a bit of a python noob! I'm trying to split a string (of length between 0 and 32 characters) into two blocks of 16 characters and save each chunk as a separate variable, but I can't work out how.

This is a pseudocode outline of what I mean:

```
text = "The weather is nice today"
split 'text' into two 16-character blocks, 'text1' and 'text2'
print(text1)
print(text2)
```

Which would output the following:

```
The weather is n
ice today
```

I'm displaying the text entered on a 2x16 character LCD connected to a raspberry pi and I need to split the text into lines to write to the LCD - I'm writing the text to the LCD like this: `lcd.message(text1 "\n" text2)`so the chunks have to be 16 characters long exactly.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `text` is not exactly 32 characters long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text can be sliced into two string variables by specifying the indices. [:16] is basically 0 to 15 and [16:] is 16 to last character in string

```
text1 = text[:16]
text2 = text[16:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "The weather is nice today"

text1, text2 = [text[i: i + 16] for i in range(0, len(text), 16)]

print(text1)
print(text2)
```

It will print:

```
The weather is n
ice today
```

Comment: This is the best approach so far because it uses *list comprehension*

Answer (score 1):

This would apply to any `text`

```
text = "The weather is nice today"
splitted = [text[i:i+16] for i  in range(0, len(text), 16)]
print (splitted) # Will print all splitted elements together
```

OR you can also do it like

```
text = "The weather is nice today"
for i in range(0, len(text), 16):
    print (text[i:i+16])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "The weather is nice today"

text1, text2 = text[:16], text[16:32]
print(text1)
print(text2)
```

Prints:

```
The weather is n
ice today
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
s = "this is a simple string that is long"
size = 8
for sl in range(0, int(len(s)/size)):
   out = s[sl:sl + size]
   print(out, len(out))
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is like a list.

You can split it or count your characters in the string.

Example:

```
word = 'www.BellezaCulichi.com'


total_characters = len(word)

print(str(total_characters))
# it show 22, 22 characters has word
```

You can split the string and get the 5 first characters

```
print(word[0:5])
# it shows:  www.B
# the first 5 characters in the string



print(word[0:15])
# split the string and get the 15 first characters
# it shows:  www.BellezaCuli
# the first 5 characters in the string
```

You can store the result of the split in a variable:

```
first_part = word[0:15]
```